# HSSF How to write result in Excel by using Constant Int column number

Tags: java, excel, selenium, hssf

I'm new to Java and Selenium, Selenium is quite fun, I'm working on Selenium WebDriver with TestNG Data Driven framework.

by refer to this tutorial
http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.sg/2014/07/framework-for-selenium-webdriver-report.html#comment-form

there is a Excel Utility where write data to excel with using HSSF

> SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath, TestCaseName, "Pass/Fail/Skip", DataSet+1, "PASS");

Instead of hardcode, I'm planning to using Constant file to replace it. eg,

> public static final String KEYWORD_PASS = "PASS";
>   public static final int COL_TEST_CASE_RESULT = 10; // put it in column no 10

so it will be like these and become more manageable

> SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, Constant.COL_TEST_CASE_RESULT, DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_PASS);

My question is how to modify the code below so I can change the String colName to int column number.

```html
public boolean writeResult(String wsName, String colName, int rowNumber, String Result){
 try{
  int sheetIndex=wb.getSheetIndex(wsName);
  if(sheetIndex==-1)
   return false;   
  int colNum = retrieveNoOfCols(wsName);
  int colNumber=-1;
  HSSFRow Suiterow = ws.getRow(0);   
  for(int i=0; i<colNum; i++){    
   if(Suiterow.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().equals(colName.trim())){
    colNumber=i;     
   }     
  }
  if(colNumber==-1){
   return false;    
  }
  HSSFRow Row = ws.getRow(rowNumber);
  HSSFCell cell = Row.getCell(colNumber);
  if (cell == null)
      cell = Row.createCell(colNumber);   
   cell.setCellValue(Result);
   opstr = new FileOutputStream(filelocation);
   wb.write(opstr);
   opstr.close();
 }catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public  void setData(String adr,String sht,int rn,int cn,String val) throws Exception{

    FileInputStream fsIP= new FileInputStream(new File(adr)); //Read the spreadsheet that needs to be updated

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fsIP); //Access the workbook

    XSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheet(sht); //Access the worksheet, so that we can update / modify it.

    Cell cell = null; // declare a Cell object

    cell = worksheet.getRow(rn).getCell(cn);   // Access the second cell in second row to update the value

    cell.setCellValue(val);  // Get current cell value value and overwrite the value

    fsIP.close(); //Close the InputStream

    FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File(adr));  //Open FileOutputStream to write updates

    wb.write(output_file); //write changes

    output_file.close();  //close the stream   
}
```

It might be helped.